# PHP/HTML: 500 Internal server error...?

Tags: php, html, iphone, webkit

The code provided in the link has problems.
When trying to go to the real webpage, it gives me a 500 internal server error.

What is wrong with the code? Anybody knows?

http://www.gdscei.com/myphp.txt

I am using iWebKit.

(I know you cannot read the text, it's Dutch. But I am not seeing any problem with pure text.)

Comment: Can you especify in which page are you getting a Internal Server Error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the script on my local server and got

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\code.php on line 62

Apparently this line:

```
echo " <a href="loggedin/index.php" class="noeffect">Klik hier om verder te gaan</a>";
```

has an error because you did not escape the double quotes. You should use this instead:

```
echo ' <a href="loggedin/index.php" class="noeffect">Klik hier om verder te gaan</a>';
```

OR (not recommended):

```
echo " <a href=\"loggedin/index.php\" class=\"noeffect\">Klik hier om verder te gaan</a>";
```

It may be the way that your server is configured to output HTTP 500 error instead of showing the PHP error when an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think that your code have any problem with 500 internal server error, this error happens when there is something wrong with .htaccess file or the cgi so you need to check if you have any of them